# Robust and Mature HTML Parser for PHP

Tags: php, html, html-parsing

Are there any robust and mature HTML parsers available for PHP? A quick skimming of PEAR didn't turn anything up (lots of classes for generating HTML, not so much for consuming), and Google taught me a lot of people have started and then abandoned a variety of parser projects.

Not interested in XML parsers (unless then can consume non-well formed HTML) or hacking it on my own with regular expressions.

**Clarification of Intent:**  I'm not interested in filtering of HTML content, I'm interesting in extracting information from HTML documents.